# why does black line is being added when image source is empty?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to create a logo upload component with image preview, and before the image source is being added I get this black line near the image border and I can't figure out why.

I tried to disable outline, border-radius, etc.. but only when an actual image is being added this black line goes away.

```html
<div class="preview-logo">
    <img src='' />
</div>
```

```css
.preview-logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.preview-logo img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.6),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185,0.46);
    background-color: #eceafd;
    border: 1px solid #3633502d;
}
```

Comment: share a codepen to understand better. A black line is too vague.

Comment: @your'e right, check out the post once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per the HTML spec for the `<img>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element):

> **The src attribute must be present**, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.

As with most HTML elements, if you don't exactly adhere the the spec, strange things can happen and the `<img>` tag is no exception. However, there's another important property that you can leverage to address issues (or non-existant `src` properties: the `alt` attribute.

**You can set the `alt` attribute to an empty string `' '` and this will be sufficient to hide the outer border that you are currently seeing due to the missing `src` property:**

```
<div class="preview-logo">
    <img src='' alt=' ' />
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you didn't have a `src` attribute set, you could consider hiding the element altogether:

```
.preview-logo img[src=''] {
    display: none;
}
```

### Example

```css
.preview-logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.preview-logo img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.6), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.46);
  background-color: #eceafd;
  border: 1px solid #3633502d;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-logo">
  <img src='' /><br /><br />
  <img src='' alt=' ' />
</div>
```